# Windows 10 and Playback Sounds device defaults

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio

My DELL laptop with Win10 is usually coupled to a HD Monitor with speakers. When I disconnect it and go mobile, Win10 doesn't automatically default to the laptop's own speakers???

Any ideas please how to get Win10 to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In playback devices (right click the volume icon in task bar), if you have multiple outputs you can disable any that are unused.  For the most part if all you use are those 2, you can disable all but internal speakers and the dell monitor.  Also, some applications bind to the connected audio and do not switch with the monitor.  You can see this often when you open the "Volume Mixer" and there is a drop down below the device.  When swapping to your now disconnected Monitor speakers you will see some applications lingering.  Closing and re-opening those applications will move them to new audio source.  Some applications you have to go into settings and set it to "Use default device"  for it to auto switch, else it will bind to whatever speakers you select.  Teamspeak is a prime example of this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

1. Plug laptop into speakers
2. Go to Playback Settings (Right click volume button)
3. Set monitor speakers to default
4. Make sure that both monitor speakers and laptop speakers are on
5. Try it out

So, by setting the monitor speakers to default, when you plug it in, Windows will choose the monitor speakers over the laptop speakers. When you unplug them, the monitor speakers become inactive and the next active speaker is chosen. That would be the laptop speakers.

Lemme know if this works!